# Beamer on VSCode mac: File `beamercolorthemeBerlin.sty' not found

Tags: beamer, mactex

I'm using Mactex and locally editing a presentation file in Beamer. When I go to use the `Berlin` color theme, I get the follolwing

> File `beamercolorthemeBerlin.sty' not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking for a colour theme? There is a theme called `Berlin` which is part of beamer

Comment: Or maybe you want to install this file: https://github.com/fneum/beamerthemeBerlin/blob/master/beamercolorthemeBerlin.sty

Answer (score 1):

In my installation, I have

```
~/tmp> locate beamercolorthemeB
/home/romano/texlive2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer-fuberlin/beamercolorthemeBerlinFU.sty
/home/romano/texlive2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bfh-ci/beamercolorthemeBFH.sty
```

So it seems that the colortheme is called `BerlinFU`. Given that you didn't post any code, I can't be sure this is the problem.